# Google AppEngine JDO enum filtering

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am having an interesting issue, which seems to be very simple but I have lack of understanding of Google AppEngine. Not too sure if the following can be done or not

As an example, say I have a model object

```
Person {
 ....
 PersonStatus status;

}
```

PersonStatus is an enum, where the values say are "ALIVE", "EXPIRED", "PARALYSED", "TMP"...

I also have a list of PersonStatus and if person status matches to anyone in the list then that person should be returned (simple contains function basically)

I tried

```
query.setFilter(":p.contains(status.toString())");
```

where p is List of String
This fails with error

```
Unsupported method <contains> while parsing expression: InvokeExpression{[ParameterExpression{p}].contains(InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{status}].toString(<none>)})}
```

and

```
query.setFilter(":p.contains(status)");
```

where p is List of PersonStatus but this fails with the error saying PersonStatus (Enum) is not the supported data type.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions? Seem very simple and I would be surprised if AppEngine doesn't support this type of operation

Comment: Don't think JDOQL "Enum.toString" would be supported by AppEngine, and "contains" certainly isn't (as the message says).

Comment: So, if I had to do something like I mentioned in my question, is there any hacky way of doing it?